# Page tab loads content from some domains but not others?

Tags: web-hosting, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I’ve created a welcome tab for a Page. When I set the Page Tab URL to pull content from http://journalism.unr.edu/facebook/welcome/, the tab comes up blank. But when I uploaded a copy of the content to a free 000webhost.com hosting account at http://rsj.netii.net/welcome/, and used that address as the Page Tab URL, the content loads just fine. What I want to know is, why?

I’ve experimented with pulling content from other URLs into my page tab:

- yahoo.com - **works**
- google.com - **doesn’t work**
- unr.edu - **works**
- journalism.unr.edu - **doesn’t work**
- unr.edu/engineering - **doesn’t work** (shows error message: “The page cannot be displayed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.”)

Does anyone know why page tabs/iframe apps load content from some domains but not others? Can anyone tell me how to fix the journalism.unr.edu web server (I have access to it, I work for the journalism school) so that page tabs can load content from it? We’d like to be able to pull content straight from our website without having to copy it over to a free hosting account.

Comment: can you post a link to the tab?

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Reynolds-School-of-Journalism/52315156165?sk=app_301124646585920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem with http://journalism.unr.edu/facebook/welcome/

But I cannot even get it to load inside of an iframe.  Maybe there's some restriction setup in the hosting or server that servers that site. Or maybe a more complex issue with the server not allowing it to be iframed from a different host domain.

Simple to test, just make an html page like.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>I hope it loads</p>
<iframe src="http://journalism.unr.edu/facebook/welcome/" width="400" height="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Also:  "unr.edu/engineering - doesn’t work (shows error message: “The page cannot be displayed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.”)"

That one is because you're pointing to a resource on the server that does not allow HTTP POSTs.

Comment: Ok, so it's an iframe problem, not a Facebook problem. That's good, that narrows down what I have to investigate. Thanks for your help!